# Обмен данными со службой Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, windows-service

Есть служба (написана мной) под Windows. Есть приложение. Средствами WinAPI можно останавливать, запускать службу из клиентского приложения (в общем, обмениваться командами). Но мне необходимо еще и передавать данные между службой и клиентским приложением. Возможно, есть какое-то готовое API?

*P.S.: Можно использовать сокеты, но, мне кажется, это не совсем практичным для данной задачи.*

Comment: Да там много всяких механизмов обмена данными между процессами.  Например named pipe. Похоже на сокеты, но совсем не сокеты. А вообще в виндовсе COM предназначен для коммуникаций между процессами

Comment: ControlService() позволяет до 128 сообщений юзерских использовать. И да, named pipe как и говорили выше.

Comment: Sergey Да. В курсе, что много. Хоть по e-mail обменивайся. Но интересует, возможно есть какое-то API.

Comment: Ещё есть обмен через PostMessage. Службы могут рассылать служебные сообщения как одному окну, так и оповещать все окна.

Comment: Без уточнения требований к обмену данными разумной подсказки не получится. Список доступных технологий здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Chorkov Предполагается обмен бинарными данными в обе стороны.

Comment: Если не хотите переделывать - пишите сокетами. Если нет - вам предложили кучу вариантов.

Comment: @MaxZS Синхронный/асинхронный обмен? (Т.е. нужно ли ждать реакции получателя данных?) Есть ли привязка клиентов к конкретным файлам на диске? (Т.е. можно ли использовать file mapping с именами файлов выбранными "естественным" образом)?

Comment: @nick_n_a сокеты - это то что мне известно лучше всего. И как бы их без проблем можно использовать. Но, возможно, есть что-то более простое и удобное - про это и был вопрос.

Comment: @Chorkov обмен асинхронный.Про файлы на диске не думал. Можно, в принципе, подумать и в эту сторону.